# How do I set advance file association in Windows 10 (while passing app parameter to open)

Tags: windows-10, file-association

I'm trying to set default to open Tableau workbooks with a connector option, and using connector argument before filename, am I doing the below right?

Below from the command prompt is working fine

```
"C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 2019.1\bin\tableau.exe" -DConnectPluginsPath=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\connector C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Book1.twb
```

But not working using ftype association

```
ftype myfile="C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 2019.1\bin\tableau.exe -DConnectPluginsPath=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\connector" %1
assoc .twb=myfile
regsvr32 /i shell32.dll
```

Seems like it's not accepting the argument

```
-DConnectPluginsPath=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\connector
```

Seems like it's accepting the parameter after starting app, not while starting app using those parameter settings.

Thanks

Comment: Your quotation marks appear to be in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternate, use this REG.exe command-line:

```
reg add hkcr\myfile\shell\open\command /ve /d "\"C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 2019.1\bin\tableau.exe\" -DConnectPluginsPath=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\connector "\"%1\""
```

This sets the `(default)` value to the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 2019.1\bin\tableau.exe" -DConnectPluginsPath=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\connector "%1"
```

Under this registry key:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myfile\Shell\Open\Command

And then run:

```
assoc .twb=myfile
```